# Asp.Net OnClick perform through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, click

I have a normal image  for delete and an Asp.Net button.
If I click the image which is inside the javascript I need to make the Asp.Net button click and perform it's operation.

Is there any way to do that from the client side:
Here is my normal Html button:

This is my Asp.Net button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

This is my code behind:

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
                //Do something//
  End Sub
```

Comment: why do you need both the buttons? can you remove asp button? and use any ajax library to call the server side code when HTML button is clicked?

Comment: I dont understand why you have two. Create the button in design view and double click it. It will generate the code for the button.

Comment: Actually I don't need an Html button and instead of that I use Image which I must use in javascript.And If I click that Image I make the buton automatically click and able to perform its operartion.

Comment: @javasocute I knew that it's creates a codebehind for the button but I have an image instead of button in the javascript and when t is clicked I need to make the Asp.Net button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID%>");
if (btn){
    btn.click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this:

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton" onclick="document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>_input').click();">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most proper way would be to do this:

In your code-behind:

```
Protected ReadOnly Property ButtonClickScript() As String
    Get
        Return Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Button1, "")
    End Get
End Property

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub
```

In aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
<img onclick="<%=ButtonClickScript() %>" />
```